# mysql inner join with having

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, having

My tables are:

```
mysql> select * from professor;
    +-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
    | empid | name   | status | salary | age  |
    +-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
    |     1 | Arun   |      1 |   2000 |   23 |
    |     2 | Benoy  |      0 |   3000 |   25 |
    |     3 | Chacko |      1 |   1000 |   36 |
    |     4 | Divin  |      0 |   5000 |   32 |
    |     5 | Edwin  |      1 |   2500 |   55 |
    |     7 | George |      0 |   1500 |   46 |
    +-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
    6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from works;
+----------+-------+---------+
| courseid | empid | classid |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |     1 |      10 |
|        2 |     2 |       9 |
|        3 |     3 |       8 |
|        4 |     4 |      10 |
|        5 |     5 |       9 |
|        6 |     1 |       9 |
|        2 |     3 |      10 |
|        2 |     1 |       7 |
|        4 |     2 |       6 |
|        2 |     4 |       6 |
|        2 |     5 |       2 |
|        7 |     5 |       6 |
|        3 |     5 |       2 |
|        6 |     4 |      10 |
+----------+-------+---------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from course;
+----------+------------+--------+
| courseid | coursename | points |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        1 | Maths      |      5 |
|        2 | Science    |      1 |
|        3 | English    |      6 |
|        4 | Social     |      4 |
|        5 | Malayalam  |     20 |
|        6 | Arts       |     25 |
|        7 | Biology    |     20 |
+----------+------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Question is :

> List those professors who have not taught any course in the three
>   classes Class 7,8,9

My query is :

```
select professor.name from professor
inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
group by works.empid
having works.classid not in (7,8,9);
```

The ouput I get is :

```
Arun    
Divin
```

The ouput I am actually required to get :

Divin

Pls help me out.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77ec7/46

Comment: I think you're supposed to work through these yourself. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: So, this appears to be homework

Comment: i think george also have no 7,8,9 or ?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
group by works.empid, works.classid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select professor.name from professor
inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
inner join course on work.courseid=course.courseid
group by works.empid
having works.classid not in (7,8,9);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select name  from professor where name not in (

 select name  from professor
 inner join works
 on professor.empid=works.empid

 where works.classid  in (7,8,9)
 group by  professor.name );
```

you will get

```
 divin
 george
```

as also george dont have 7,8,9